The construction from the naturals to the complex.
I don't know if this question is appropriate here. I am trying to get a better understanding of the reals and complex analysis e.g. in general topology we generalize sequences for nets. I know from ZFC the existence of the set of natural numbers and that the equivalence of the well-ordering principle(considering the standard ordering for the naturals) and induction. I understand from Grothendieck group, then we can construct the integers and show that it's an integral domain with the specific ordering. From the localization of rings, we can construct the rationals from the integers. From dedekind cuts, then we can construct the reals. It's pretty straightforward to construct the complex numbers from $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$. Is there a resource, I can find that someone already did all of this(since I have not thoroughly constructed all of this myself)?
the reason why I ask is that I feel that I have some overall understanding of how this works, but I don't have all the details myself e.g. extending ordering from the naturals to the integers to the rationals to the reals or another example would be the category implications from this construction.

Another way to get from rationals to reals, of course, is via completion instead of Dedekind cuts.  I prefer completion because as far as I recall, defining multiplication on Dedekind cuts requires a case-by-case construction depending on signs.  (One way of putting it: the set of Cauchy sequences is a subring of $\mathbb{Q}^{\mathbb{N}}$; the set of sequences converging to 0 is a maximal ideal of that subring; and therefore the quotient ring gives you a field which you can call $\mathbb{R}$.)

And yet another construction is to take the set of functions $f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ such that ${ f(m+n) - f(m) - f(n) \mid m, n \in \mathbb{Z} }$ is bounded, which turns out to form a commutative ring using composition of functions as multiplication.  Then the set of bounded such functions is a maximal ideal, and the quotient again is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.  (This construction has the property that it's easier to do actual calculations with such functions.)

If I remember correctly, all of this is done in a book by Landau, "Grundlagen der Analysis", and there's an English translation "Foundations of Analysis". It has too high a detail/idea ratio for my taste, but it may be just what you want since you've already seen the ideas. (Disclaimer: I read this book about 60 years ago, so my memory of it might be inaccurate.)

@AndreasBlass Thanks will check it out
